# Dell Inspiron 1525 - touchpad not listed under mouse after Vista reinstall

Tags: windows-vista, touchpad, dell-inspiron

Touchpad is not responding after Vista reinstall. When I go to Control Panel > Mouse, touchpad is not listed. I think that I have latest drivers installed. It is listed under Device Manager > Mice and other pointing devices. Is there anything else I can check

Comment: install the latest drivers again: ftp://ftp.dell.com/pages/Drivers/inspiron-1525-all.html#Input

Comment: Thanks. Dell Touchpad tab is now listed under Mouse properties. If I go to Click to change DellTouchpad settings, I get Synaptics DELL Touchpad has stopped working with Close Program in the dialog box. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea. Ask this the Dell Support.